# Codeigniter configuration file load

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to use a new file containing constants in Codeigniter so I created the file `/config/labels.php`

When I try to load it in my controller using `$this->config->load('labels');` and it throws 
`application/config/labels.php file does not appear to contain a valid configuration array.`

However when I put the code in the constants.php file everything works well.

```
labels.php 

<?php
define('CLI_CIVILITE','Civilité');
define('CLI_NOM','Nom');
define('CLI_PRENOM','Prenom');
```

Comment: -1: There is a lot of questions about codeigniter configuration files and you can make some searches before asking something that is already answered. I know it because I've answered a few with the same subject and problems. Have you even opened the codeigniter documentation? It is so clear and easy!

Comment: Yes I have... but the answer below was never stated in any configuration. Keep up the good votes:) thanks...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The config file should contain an array `$config`
Thats why it throws the error.

When the config class loads the config file, it checks if `$config` was set.
If not it will throw an error.

As far as I know there is no feature to load your own file with custom constants.
As of now you will have to add those constants to `application/config/constants.php`

Comment: So what is the best way to create some Java style .properties files in Codeigniter?

Comment: add your constants to the constants.php file. And if you are looking to load the constants dynamically, you can extend the `CI_Loader` with a method `constant` to load your file, and call it like `$this->load->constants('label')`

Answer (score 2):

In the constants file, define a variable like below:

```
$ORDER_STATUS = array(
    '0' => 'In Progress',
    '1' => 'On Hold',
    '2' => 'Awaiting Review',
    '3' => 'Completed',
    '4' => 'Refund Requested',
    '5' => 'Refunded');
```

Then, in the controller:

```
function __construct()
{
    $this->config->load('$ORDER_STATUS');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

write in your config example and save as banned_idcard.php

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
$config ['banned_idcard'] = array (
'23104013',
'2010201103',
'11106062',
);
```

And in ur Controoler

```
<?php
function __construct () {
$banned_idcards = $this->config->load('banned_idcard');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your config `/config/labels.php`:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
$config = array(
    'CLI_CIVILITE' => 'Civilité',
    'CLI_NOM' => 'Nom',
    'CLI_PRENOM' => 'Prenom'
);
```

in your controller:

```
$this->config->load('labels');
var_dump((array)$this->config); //show all the configs including those in the labels.php
```